# Search in text using multiple words with AND OR operators

Tags: python

Consider this draft text paragraph:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus iaculis imperdiet hendrerit. Aliquam vitae eleifend ex. Aenean molestie mi vel mauris blandit sagittis. Cras dictum ac nibh nec malesuada. Fusce dolor ex, vulputate id ipsum eget, varius condimentum lectus. Fusce accumsan nisl eget tincidunt elementum. Suspendisse eu pellentesque odio.

I want to check this text if contains words **('Lorem' AND 'ipsum') OR 'dolor'**

How I can do this in Python?

Use case:
Queries are saved to database, so, the user can remove or add or edit queries in an admin area.

Comment: hint: can be done using `in` operator

Comment: @EricFinn I'm thinking to save it in an SQLite database and query on it.

Comment: What's the exact use case? does it need to work with any query and any text? 
I'd personally do:
```
tokens = set(text.split())
answer = ('lorem' in tokens and 'ipsum' tokens) or 'dolor' in tokens
```

Comment: If the text had 'dolors' should that be considered a match? What about "Dolor"? Please clarify what you mean by "words".

Comment: @RoryDaulton The user enter queries to need to be checked against a text like this one `('Lorem' AND 'ipsum') OR 'dolor'`

Comment: That does not answer my question. What kind of "check" do you want? Do other forms of a word count? Does different capitalization count? In a computer program, you must be very clear in your mind just what you want the computer to do, you need to let us know just what that is.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus iaculis imperdiet hendrerit. Aliquam vitae eleifend ex. Aenean molestie mi vel mauris blandit sagittis. Cras dictum ac nibh nec malesuada. Fusce dolor ex, vulputate id ipsum eget, varius condimentum lectus. Fusce accumsan nisl eget tincidunt elementum. Suspendisse eu pellentesque odio."

result = ('Lorem' in text and 'ipsum' in text) or 'dolor' in text
print(result)
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: I'd tokenize it first. For example, "dolores" would match with this solution

Comment: How I can transform this query `('Lorem' AND 'ipsum') OR 'dolor'` into this `('Lorem' in text and 'ipsum' in text) or 'dolor' in text`

Comment: You can see https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html or write a binary expression tree https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree from scratch to implement your request executor

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus iaculis imperdiet hendrerit. Aliquam vitae eleifend ex. Aenean molestie mi vel mauris blandit sagittis. Cras dictum ac nibh nec malesuada. Fusce dolor ex, vulputate id ipsum eget, varius condimentum lectus. Fusce accumsan nisl eget tincidunt elementum. Suspendisse eu pellentesque odio."

word_lists = [['Lorem', 'ipsum'], ['dolor']]
result = any(all(w in text for w in word_list) for word_list in word_lists)
print result
```

> True

You can add elements to word_lists if you need to add more condidions.

Answer (score 0):

@ Lhassan Baazzi

```
import re

r = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus iaculis imperdiet hendrerit. Aliquam vitae eleifend ex. Aenean molestie mi vel mauris blandit sagittis. Cras dictum ac nibh nec malesuada. Fusce dolor ex, vulputate id ipsum eget, varius condimentum lectus. Fusce accumsan nisl eget tincidunt elementum. Suspendisse eu pellentesque odio."

if re.search('Lorem' and 'ipsum',r) or re.search('dolor',r):
    print 'Exists'
```